# Hook variable inside of anonymous function

Tags: javascript, hook, anonymous-function

I want to hook a variable called `test` using an anonymous function.

```js
!function() {
    let test = true;
    return !test // it writes true to console but i need to write false
}()
```

I except that code will show in console `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: function executes `!true` which the function returns `false` and you run `!false` which makes it true. My guess is you want `!!function()`

Comment: What do you think the initial `!` does?  Why is it there?

Comment: Can you explain what "to hook a variable" means? Also, your example does not log anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inversion happens two times in your code. One is inside the function, and one is outside the function. So, `!!true` is always `true`.

Here is the code which has one of the inversions removed.

```js
let res = function() {
    let test = true;
    return !test // it writes true to console but i need to write false
}();

console.log(res);
```